# Area of the surface

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Compute the area between the surfaces $(x^2+y^2)^2=a^2(x^2-y^2)$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2.$

My attempt:

I take the first case $z\geq 0$:

$$x=x$$
$$y=y$$
$$z=\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}$$

then 
$$T_x=(1,0,\frac {-x}{\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}})$$
$$T_x=(0,1,\frac {-y}{\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}})$$

Then the area of the surface is:

$$A(S)=\int_S d\sigma=\int\int_D \frac {a}{\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}}dxdy$$

By parameterization:

$$x=rcost$$
$$y=rsint$$

then $r=a\sqrt{cos(2t)}\implies t\in [0, \frac {\pi}4]$ and $r\in[0,a\sqrt{cos(2t)}]$

$A(S)=(a^2-\sqrt{2})$. But that's a wrong answer, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by the "area between the surfaces".

Answer (score 1):

Using parametric form $x = rcost$ and $y = rsint$ the equation of the curve is $r^2 = a^2cos2t$ and the equation of the sphere is $x = rcost$, $y = rsint$, $z = \sqrt{a^2 - r^2}$

The integral of surface area is given by

$$\int\int_R\sqrt{EG - F^2}drdt$$

$$E = (\frac{\partial x}{\partial r})^2 +(\frac{\partial y}{\partial r})^2 + (\frac{\partial z}{\partial r})^2 = \frac{a^2}{a^2 - r^2}$$

$$G = (\frac{\partial x}{\partial t})^2 + (\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})^2 + (\frac{\partial z}{\partial t})^2 = r^2$$

$$F = (\frac{\partial x}{\partial r})(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}) + (\frac{\partial y}{\partial r})(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}) + (\frac{\partial z}{\partial r})(\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}) = 0$$

Therefore the integral for the surface area for $y > 0$ at the upper sphere is

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{a\sqrt{cos2t}}\sqrt{\frac{a^2r^2}{a^2 - r^2}}drdt$$

$$= a^2(\frac{\pi}{4} + 1 - \sqrt{2})$$

Since we have $y < 0$ and the lower sphere plus there are two branches, the total surface area should be 8 times the above.  Hence the total surface area is

$$a^2(2\pi + 8 - 8\sqrt{2})$$